# In c#, determine interfaces implemented by an object at runtime

Tags: c#, interface, runtime

I know there are ways to determine at runtime if an object implements a particular interface. What I'm wondering is if there's a way to determine at runtime *all* of the interfaces an object implements without looking for any one interface in particular.

I'd really rather not have to check for each interface one by one - even using asynchronous processing that seems clunky and inelegant to me.

I'm  currently looking into reflection, but if there is a less resource-intensive, in-language way to do it I'd prefer that.

Any ideas?

Comment: just google for "get interfaces of type C#". Gave me link to MSDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Type.GetInterfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getinterfaces?view=netcore-3.1) will return you the types of the interfaces implemented by the type of an object. For example:

```
var interfaces = someObject.GetType().GetInterfaces();
```